# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, openlayers

I'm a beginner with Angular and OpenLayers and I was trying to import a geojson file which i put in the assets folder. I also tried to import a json file from the same folder and had no issues there.

```
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import bundeslandData from 'src/assets/Bundeslandsgrenzen.geojson';
import test from 'src/assets/test.json';
```

When I'm trying to do it like this I'm getting the message:

> Cannot find module 'src/assets/Bundeslandsgrenzen.geojson' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

I wasn't able to find anything with a similar issue yet, so if anyone already found a solution please link it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't know .geojson file and suppose it's a module.
It knows .json and load it withour error.
Try to rename your .geojson to .json.